# fancybox 2 and titles

Tags: jquery, fancybox, title, fancybox-2

I'm using the thumbnail "alt" attribute for the caption.

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         beforeShow : function() {
         var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

         this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

         this.title = alt;
         }
    });
```

but this doesn't work as soon as I want to use the "over" style for the title.

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         helpers : {
         title: {
         type: 'over'
                }
                    }
    });
```

It doesn't work when I want to use them together for some reason.

Comment: do you mean over or hover?

Comment: @circle73 : the OP meant `over` as API option

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all the API options within the same selector initialization like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
        this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
        this.title = alt;
    },
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    }
});
```

otherwise the second overrides the first.

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B7EUJ/)**